# I create the menu at electron by mac, but how can i hide the default menu "Electron"?

Tags: electron

I create the menu code like this, when I run it at mac, the first menu is always a default 'Electron', how can I delete it?

```
const mainMenu = Menu.buildFromTemplate(
    [
        ...(isMac ? [{
            label: 'Test',
            submenu: [
                { role: 'about' },
                { type: 'separator' },
                { role: 'services' },
                { type: 'separator' },
                { role: 'hide' },
                { role: 'hideothers' },
                { role: 'unhide' },
                { type: 'separator' },
                { role: 'quit' }
            ]
        }] : []) as MenuItemConstructorOptions[],
        {
            label: 'File',
            submenu: [
                isMac ? { role: 'close' } : { role: 'quit' }
            ] as MenuItemConstructorOptions[]
        },
        ...... and so on
```

[the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A29tW.png)

Comment: i'd like to know  too, as far as i know, this one is hard coded. Because there's not even a role says that is the first menu.

Comment: thank you, do you know how can I change the name like the vscode? The first menu is "Code”, but the first submenu is "About visual Studio Code", they are not the same name.